# Azure Powershell Workflow : Failed to convert 'System.Activities.InArgument`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I have a couple of Azure Powershell Workflow runbooks that copy a production database and then run cleanup scripts against it and scale it down to generate dev and stage environemnts. I started getting the error "Failed to convert 'System.Activities.InArgument`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'" from the parent workbook when I was editing it. I recreated the problem in a set of test runbooks: Test_Child and Test_Parent.

Test_Child is just an empty shell meant to receive a single input string.

```
workflow Test_Child
{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String] $Input
    )
}
```

Test_Parent connects to Azure automation and executes the child workbook. If I run both processes in this order it fails. If I run either one separately or reverse the order of execution it succeeds.

```
workflow Test_Parent
{
             
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'

    Write-Output "Logging into Azure AD ..."
    
    Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID `
                -ApplicationID $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID `
                -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint `
                -ServicePrincipal
  
    try 
            {
            
                Test_Child -Input "input" 
            }
    catch
            {
            
            exit
            }
}
```

If I execute the parent runbook I get an error.

```
Failed
Failed to convert 'System.Activities.InArgument`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'.
```

**If I remove the runbook call the process completes.**

Test_Parent with runbook call removed:

```
workflow Test_Parent
{
             
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'

    Write-Output "Logging into Azure AD ..."
    
    Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID `
                -ApplicationID $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID `
                -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint `
                -ServicePrincipal
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Logging into Azure AD ...


PSComputerName        : localhost
PSSourceJobInstanceId : [My PSSourceJobInstanceId]
Environments          : {AzureCloud, AzureUSGovernment, AzureChinaCloud, AzureGermanCloud}
Context               : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext
```

**If I only call the workbook the process completes as well.**

Here is the runbook Test_Parent with the Azure automation connection call removed:

```
workflow Test_Parent
{
             
     try 
            {
            
                Test_Child -Input "input" 
            }
    catch
            {
            
            exit
            }
}
```

The output

```
Completed
```

**If I reverse the order of execution it completes.**

```
workflow Test_Parent
{
    try 
            {
            
                Test_Child -Input "input" 
            }
    catch
            {
            
            exit
            }
             
  
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'

    Write-Output "Logging into Azure AD ..."
    
    Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID `
                -ApplicationID $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID `
                -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint `
                -ServicePrincipal
            
}
```

Output

```
Completed
Logging into Azure AD ...


PSComputerName        : localhost
PSSourceJobInstanceId : [My PSSourceJobInstanceId]
Environments          : {AzureCloud, AzureUSGovernment, AzureChinaCloud, AzureGermanCloud}
Context               : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext
```

Any idea why making the automation connection and then executing the workbook creates a data type mismatch error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. In our Test environment the runbooks ran without problem. In our UAT environment, which was set up at a later time, we had the same error as you.
After some investigation I noticed that both environments used a different version of the Az.Accounts module. (2.5.2 in Test, 2.6 in UAT).
After upgrading the Az.Accounts module to 2.7.2 the issue seems to have dissapeared, so i guess it was a bug in the 2.6 version.